# VS Code - Need a way to add shortcut key <esc> to close the panel if the panel has focus

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, window-focus

Currently in the process of coding MQL4/5 in VSCode because of the awesome extensions. Finding that a few of the (my) most used keyboard shortcuts are actually configurable. Looking for a short answer to emulate the <kbd>Esc</kbd> keypress after compiling source. My screen is large and having to hunt down the little **x** at the lower right corner is the only way I found but not preferable.

Panel is open:
[image: Panel open]

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Terminal closes:
[image: Terminal closes]

Comment: This question has a bunch of noise like MQL or compiling source, but doesn't quite specify what exactly "closing terminal" is. Closing the whole panel including terminal? Ending the specific terminal session? Closing/hiding just the terminal tab of the panel?I assume the 1st even though it's not "closing terminal" because clicking on some "x" was mentioned, but you need to be as accurate as possible when asking questions.

Comment: Simply closing the terminal is enough. What happens is the terminal is launched to execute the compile - then, it retains focus. Once the compile is successful, and the output tab reflects this success, the terminal is no longer needed. I'm new to json/js - and have seen a lot of examples in vscode but haven't been able to connect the dots (yet). If there is quick solution whereby <esc> closes the in-focus terminal, that would be a nice to have.

Comment: On screenshot you have Output tab focused rather than Terminal. Do you want the keybind to work for both or just Output?

Comment: Added a few pics to describe the need. Thanks for the advice! Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like the entire frame to be closed as if the closing 'x' was pressed.

Comment: Panel*. Let's pause for a second and get as accurate as possible...  What do you need focused for the keybind to work - the entire panel, Output tab, Terminal tab, both tabs, ...? **Please** answer with proper VSCode terms.

Comment: I'm new to vscode - I apologize if my terminology isn't accurate. That said, when I 'open' a 'terminal' either from the menubar, using the the keystring <ctrl> + '~', or by launching it from a json/js task, the 'window' that is in focus varies - I see what you mean now. The 'window' has focus - even though there are five off-the-shelf 'tabs' in the 'container' (window'). For the purpose of this discussion, I would like one keystroke (preferably esc) to close the entire 'container' regardless of which 'tab' has focus - as long as the 'window' or any of its child objects has focus. See pic #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the entire **panel** if it has focus, you can use this keybind in your `keybindings.json`:

```json
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
        "when": "panelFocus"
    }
```

This will work problemlessly with most panel tabs, like **Output**. It might not work with **Terminal** if your setup is passing key presses to terminal. If so, you need to look at `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` setting and add `workbench.action.closePanel` there.

You should also check out:

- [when contexts](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts)
- [built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands), more specifically:

> **Note**: You can review the full set of VS Code commands via the Keyboard Shortcuts editor **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**. The Keyboard Shortcuts editor lists all commands built into VS Code or contributed by extensions, along with their keybindings and visibility when clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Works now - just had to configure the when clause correctly.  The when clause = "when": "focusPanel=Terminal"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by statement above. If it's only terminal (which is not according to comments) then it would be `terminalFocus` rather than that. But glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vim mode, you need to add a `when context` like this:

```json
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
        "when": "view.terminal.visible"
    }
```

Without this you never went out of insert mode using escape key.